# How To Get Selected RadioButton Object From The RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net

How To Get The Selected RadioButton Object From The RadioButtonList in the Event of SelectedIndexChanged ??

Well for more description

i need to catch the radiobutton selected in the radiobuttonlist to focus on it when the radiobuttonlist autopostback

Comment: what do mean actually radiobutton object means? Getting the text given to the radiobutton?

Comment: i mean catch the object of the radiobutton to call the focus function of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}_{1}').focus();", RadioButtonList1.ClientID, RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex);

    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this) != null && ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(RadioButtonList1, typeof(RadioButtonList), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
    else
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(RadioButtonList), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
protected void rbl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList rbList = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        ListItem selItem = rbList.Items[rbList.SelectedIndex];
        selItem.Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: didnt work fine it did select it ok but i need the focus on it while i put this radiobuttonlist in a div scroll that when i select 1 in the end and i focus on it the scroll will go to it :S